# Помогите советом, как подключить php sdk QIWI

Tags: php, api, sdk, qiwi

Я перечитал все API QIWI, понял как создать платеж и т.д но не могу понять как подключить само ядро api
https://developer.qiwi.com/ru/bill-payments/
Выдает тону ошибок аля fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Curl\Curl' not found

Мой код

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

require_once("billpayments.php");

const SECRET_KEY = 'тут_код';

$billPayments = new Qiwi\Api\BillPayments(SECRET_KEY);

$publicKey = 'тут_код';
$params = [
  'publicKey' => $publicKey,
  'amount' => 200,
  'billId' => '88005553535'
];

$link = $billPayments->createPaymentForm($params);

echo $link;

?>
```

Comment: Через `composer require qiwi/bill-payments-php-sdk`

Comment: @ArchDemon кое как установил, там установилось много папок и файлов, что именно в скрипте подключать?

Comment: `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`